# Convert AES-CBC to multithreaded class

Tags: c++, multithreading, encryption

I'm student and doing research work about Advanced Encryption Standard (AES).
I choose AES-256 CBC. I'm trying to encrypt text files with threads (1 thread - 1 file)

Encryption is OK, but decryption has problem. When I try to decrypt file, it has undecrypted strings. I read some documents about AES and found that AES CBC has no opportunity to encrypt files multithreaded because of initialization vector (IV), it's unic for each file.

Can I convert AES-CBC to multithreaded class?

Comment: You can only parallelize the decryption but not the encryption.

Comment: ^^^^ what he said. [CBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)) is a synchronous mode of operation for encryption. And you can certainly parallelize all the *files* you want as independent encryptions or decryptions, but single-file encryption is a synchronous operation.